# Trigger input on Gitlab Ci

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, inquirer

I'm so curious about trigger input on gitlab CI pipeline *cmiiw.
So, the main problem when there's any prompt on Node.js like this,

**Ubuntu**

[image]

But when i'm trying to implementation into Gitlab CI, there's any error something like this

**Gitlab.CI**

[image]

This is my `gitlab.ci.yml` script

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

all_tests:
  script:
   - npm install
   - npm run setup
   - John Doe \n
   - npm run test
```

Answer (score 2):

First, CI best-practices suggest you create a `--force` or `--no-interactive` variant of your installer, to omit interactive input in case of automated deploys.

A workaround could be to use the [`yes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) unix util. This util lets you feed a string to interactive input like this (in your case):

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

all_tests:
  script:
   - npm install
   - yes 'Gitlab CI' | npm run setup
   - npm run test
```

This will answer 'Gitlab CI' to all questions asked so its rather limited.

Btw; I think you mean `.gitlab-ci.yml` instead of `travis.ci.yml` in your question?

Comment: Ah i see, anyway i have 2 input for example. Is that works when there any input again? For example, `npm run setup` has 2 trigger input, like username & password. So can i doing that with this method?
`yes 'Gitlab CI' | npm run setup` yes `password` | npm run setup`

I'm doing this for setup DB. I think it's a good idea using prompt for connecting to DB.